# Every Cover of a Compact Real Interval by Open Intervals Has a Finite Subcover where only Consecutive Sets Overlap?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-verification

Intuitively this seems true and would be a useful lemma in proving the fundamental theorem of calculus without assuming continuity of the derivative, i.e. that if $f$ is differentiable on $[a, b$ and the derivative is Riemann integrable then $\int_a^b f' = f(b) - f(a)$. **But is it true and if so is there any standard terminology for such a cover ?** My attempt at a proof follows.

---

Let $I = [a, b]$ be a closed bounded interval in $\mathbb R$. Then (Hiene-Borel theorem) every open cover of open intervals has a finite sub-cover. We can assume that the open intervals have distinct R-endpoints, as for any two with the same R-endpoint one must be contained within the other and the smaller one (or either if the same L-endpoint) can be discarded without affecting the cover.

Then these open intervals $\{O_i\ = (a_i, b_i)\}_{i = 1, n}$ can be ordered by their R-endpoints $\{b_i\}_{i = 1, n}$ in a strictly ascending sequence $b_1 < b_2, ...< b_n$.

**Claim**:

from such a set $\{O_i = (a_i, b_i)\}_{i = 1, n}$ we can select a subset which covers $[a, b]$, renumbered as $\{O'_j = (a'_i, b'_1)\}_{j = 1, m}$ in strictly ascending sequence $b'_1 < b'_2, ...< b'_m$ such that for $|i - j| > 1$ then $O'_i \cap O'_j = \emptyset$ and for $|i - j| = 1$ then $O'_i \cap O'_j \not= \emptyset$.

**Construction:**

Choose $O'_1$ from intervals $O_i$ having  $a \in O_i$ and maximizing $b_i$ among such intervals.

Iteratively, stop if $b$ is in the last chosen interval $O'_j$, otherwise, ...
Chose $O'_{j+1}$ from intervals $O_i$ having  $b'_j \in O_i$ and maximizing $b_i$ among such intervals.

Then the set $\{O'_j\}  $ fulfills the requirements.

**Proof:**

Since the set $\{O_i\}  $ covers $[a, b]$ then for $a$ in step1 and for every $b'_j$ in the iteration there is an $O_i$ which contains it and since the endpoints are unique there is exactly one which maximizes $b_j$.

Since the $O_i$ chosen as $O'_{j+1}$ contains $b'_j$ and is open then it has a non-empty intersection with $O'_j$. I.e. consecutive open intervals intersect.

The $O_i$ chosen as $O'_{j+1}$ cannot intersect any interval prior to $O'_j$ as this would require it to have been chosen previously in order to maximize $b_j$.

Comment: The proof of Fundamental Theorem of Calculus is handled more simply by the use of mean value theorem. Why do you need Heine Borel (specific version being discussed here)?

Comment: @ParamanandSingh. Thanks for your interest. I'm reading a paper by Graves dealing with Riemann integration in Banach spaces, theorem 4, available here https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1927-029-01/S0002-9947-1927-1501382-X/S0002-9947-1927-1501382-X.pdf I was looking for a way to clarify his construction. I would however be pleased to find a simpler proof in this context if you have a reference ?

Comment: You may have a look at theorem 7.34, page 162, "Mathematical Analysis" by Tom Apostol. The same proof can also be found in my blog https://paramanands.blogspot.com/2012/07/the-riemann-integral-part-2.html?m=0 (search for "Fundamental Theorem").

Comment: @ParamanandSingh As far as I understand it, the mean value theorem only applies to real-valued functions and doesn't hold for Banach space valued functions. So, yes, the proof is really easy in the real case but less so in the general case. In the real case you can pick your partition and then use MVT. In the general case with Graves' proof the differentiable points are chosen first (using Hiene-Borel).

Comment: If $f:[0,1]\to X$ is differentiable where $X$ is a Banach space and $f'$ is Riemann integrable then $(\Lambda\circ f)'=\Lambda\circ f'$ is Riemann integrable for $\Lambda\in X^*$; hence the scalar-valued  FTC implies the Banach-space-valued FTC.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Thanks, that's a nice approach for a real Banach space but I'm not so sure about a complex space ?

Comment: @TomCollinge A complex Banach space _is_ a real Banach space...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I don't follow complex is real  - e.g. https://mathoverflow.net/q/255641 and if $\Lambda \in X^*$ then $(\Lambda \circ f)'$ is complex not real so how does real FTC help ?

Comment: @TomCollinge I don't see the relevnce of anything at that link. Informally: Suppose $X$ is a complex vector space. To "make $X$ a real vector space" we need to define $\lambda x$ for $\lambda\in\Bbb R$, $x\in X$. Define $\lambda x$ to be the original product of $\lambda$ and $x$ (if $\lambda\in\Bbb R$ then $\lambda\in\Bbb C$.)

Comment: @TomCollinge Or more formally: Say  $X$ is  a complex vector space. Then formally we have an ordered triple $(X,+,p)$, where $p:\Bbb C\times X\to X$ is the function defining scalar multiplication, ie $\lambda x$ is defined to be $p(\lambda, x)$. Now let $X_\Bbb R=(X, +, p')$, where $p'=p|_{\Bbb R\times X}$; then $X_\Bbb R$ is a real vector space.

Comment: @TomCollinge Now for FTC: Say $X$ iis a complex Banach space and $f:[0,1]\to X$ is differentiable. Define $\tilde f:[0,1]\to X_\Bbb R$ by $\tilde f(t)=f(t)$.  Then $\tilde f$ is differentiable and $(\tilde f)'(t)=f'(t)$, so FTC for $X_\Bbb R$ implies FTC for $X$.

Comment: @TomCollinge The things at that link show that there are theorems for real  Banach spaces that do not hold for complex Banach spaces, and/or vice versa. I didn't say the two were synonymous; if $X$ is a complex vector  space there  may well be theorems that hold for $X$ but not for $X_\Bbb R$ or vice versa. So what? It's true that FTC for $X$ is immediate from FTC for $X_\Bbb R$, as above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be proved via a kind of "topological induction" argument - just like Heine-Borel itself. *(See [this survey paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1208.0973) for more on the method; there it's called "real induction.")*

Consider a covering $C$ of a compact real interval $[a,b]$. Let $F$ be the set of points in $[a,b]$ which are "nicely reachable" by $C$: that is, $x\in F$ iff there is a $D\subseteq C$ which covers $[a,x]$ and has the intersection property you want relative to $[a,x]$. Clearly $a\in F$, so $F\not=\emptyset$. Now let $c=\sup(F)$. Some element of $C$ covers $c$, and thinking about how far "to the left" this element reaches we see that $c\in F$ as well. But then if $c\not=b$, that same element of $C$ lets us extend $F$ a bit "to the right" past $c$, contradicting the definition of $c$. So $c=b$ and $c\in F$. But this proves the desired claim.

I've been a bit slippery in the above argument; it's a good exercise to fill in all the steps, and in particular to formally express "the intersection property you want relative to $[a,x]$."

Comment: "real induction", excellent. (I know the method, didn't know it had a name.)

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich To be fair I'm not sure it's an accepted technical term, that's just what it's called by at least one person.

Comment: The peripatetic typo-chaser found "hte" in your A. Hence my edit. Earlier today, for "\forall" I typed "\gotall" which almost makes sense

Comment: Very interesting. I have recently seen this method used to show that a (regulated) function which has left and right limits everywhere in a compact interval is the uniform limit of step functions (http://www.ueltschi.org/teaching/2016-MA258/analysisIII.pdf p.15)

Comment: @TomCollinge It comes up a lot. $[0,1]$ is connected (suppose $0\in A$ and $A$ is clopen; show that $t\in A$ for every  $t\in[0,1]$ by "induction").

Answer (score 10):

In fact, an open cover of $X$ where any point of $x$ is in at most $n$ elements of the cover is called a cover of order $n$, and such covers are used in the covering dimension in general topology: a space has $\dim(X) \le n$ iff every finite cover of $X$ has a refinement of order $\le n+1$. (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_covering_dimension) for more info.)

A theorem by Lebesgue shows that $\dim([0,1])=1$ and so refinements of order $2$ (which is what you want) exist. If we are in an ordered space and we take covers of open intervals we get our minimally overlapping sets as you desire.

Comment: Thanks. That's a very interesting background on the matter. - close thing which answer got the tick. The "real induction" answer is more directly related to the proof.

Answer (score 1):

That version of FTC is trivial:

> > **FTC** If $f:[a,b]\to\Bbb R$ is differentiable and $f'$ is Riemann integrable then $\int_a^b f'=f(b)-f(a)$.

Proof: Say $a=x_0<x_1<\dots<x_n=b$. MVT shows that there exist $\xi_j\in(x_{j-1},x_j)$ with $$f(b)-f(a)=\sum_{j=1}^n(f(x_j)-f(x_{j-1}))=\sum_{j=1}^n(x_j-x_{j-1})f'(\xi_j).$$That last sum is a Riemann sum for $\int_a^b f'$, so it is within $\epsilon$ of $\int_a^b f'$ if $\max_j(x_j-x_{j-1})<\delta$.

**Heh:** I sometimes conjecture that the above is why Riemann defined the integral exactly the way he did...

The thing about covers of $[0,1]$ is also not hard:

> > **Lemma:** If three open intervals have a point in common then one of the intervals is contained in the union of the other two.

The proof of  that is simple.

Now say  $I_1,\dots,I_n$ are open intervals and $[0,1]\subset\bigcup I_j$. Extract a minimal subfamily $J_1,\dots,J_m$ that still covers $[0,1]$. Minimality shows that  no point lies in more than two of the $J_k$, by the lemma; hence the $J_k$ can be ordered in the way you want.

(Choose $L_1=(a_1, b_1)=J_{k_1}$ so $0\in L_1$. Now there is exactly one $L_2=(a_2,b_2)=J_{k_2}$ with $b_1\in L_2$. Etc. Now, for example, $L_1\cap L_3=\emptyset$, since $x\in L_1\cap L_3$ implies that also  $x\in L_2$.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer and comments. I think the "real induction" answer is something which leads to the most direct proof.